# How to write a class method in Python that captures the name of the instance and apply some action on it

Tags: python, oop

I don't know if it's possible but here is what I want( or dream of...):

```
class A:
     method1:
       return something
     method2:
       return something else
     method3:
       return(some_action, the_name_of_instance)
     more_methods:
```

In another words, if `class A` is instantiated as:

```
inst_a = A("some")
```

`method3` should know the name of the instance(`inst_a`) by this time and it will apply some action defined by the user.

Therefore, from user point of view, the action is applied onto `inst_a` as soon as the method is called as in `inst_a.method3()`

Comment: You can't; objects are created *before they are assigned*. And you can store the object in lists, or dictionaries, or other structures and there won't be a name at all.

Comment: Think about it; what would the name be when you do `somelist = [A('some'), A('more')]`?

Comment: what is `method3` supposed to return if you do `inst_b = inst_a; inst_b.method3()`? Are you going to have the same object return different things based on the variable it's assigned to? What if it doesn't have a name (ie: it's an element in a list)?

Comment: One trick would be to inspect `globals` and `locals` function of Python but horrible way of doing it. In fact you need to rethink the design

Comment: @flamenco: nope, sorry, I don't tonight.

Comment: Probably `somelist[0]` and `somelist[1]` (hypothetically, of course). I think a better example is a statement of simply `A('some').method3`: no saved reference at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how python works - a single PyObject (an instance) might go by any number of names, and you can't thus put a single name on something:

```
my_instance = MyClass()
my_second_instance = my_instance # what's the "name" of that instance now? there's two handles for it, now.
```

Also, there's many cases where your instance doesn't have a name at all - for example, if it's just created "temporarily" when created to be directly passed to a function.

```
print pickle.dumps(MyClass()) # the new instance doesn't even get a long-lived name at all
```

All in all, I think you intend to break the isolation between the state of the object and the reference to that object -- which is almost certainly not a good idea. If you need a unique identifier, use the built-in `id` function: `id(self)`.

**EDIT** https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney correctly pointed out that you have to be careful with `id()`, because you have no guarantee that after the end of life of one object, another object can't get the same id, which, by the way, in CPython is actually the memory address of the underlyin `PyObject`.

Comment: Use `id` with caution. If the object is deleted, another object could then have that `id`.

Comment: flamenco: if there is *another* object with the same `id`, that object will be alive. Your whole approach seems flawed, and there's no technical way to fix it.

Comment: What if each instance will be created in different threads? Would they have different id?

Comment: @flamenco: please read the documentation yourself. The answer is yes, `id` is unique for all **simultaneously** existing objects, but you cannot easily ensure that one thread isn't destructing its object and replacing it with another one at the same address. Your approach is flawed. Find another one.